# gdi functions are crashed

Tags: windows, gdi

Im getting strange access violation from gdi functions. My application is like a graphic engine, multiple threads will request drawing of different graphic objects. A single thread will draw all graphic objects to a memory DC. The synchronization between these threads are correct.

When I prepared userdump, access violation is occurred from two threads. Following is the callstack of two threads, GetTextExtentPoint32 and CreateFontIndirect are crashed.

```
// Access violation from Draw Request thread.
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xe
ntdll!RtlRaiseStatus+0x26
ntdll!RtlpUnWaitCriticalSection+0x3b
ntdll!RtlLeaveCriticalSection+0x1d
gdi32!GdiRealizationInfo+0x88
lpk!FontHasWesternScript+0x1e
lpk!LpkUseGDIWidthCache+0x89
gdi32!GetTextExtentPointWInternal+0x100
gdi32!GetTextExtentPoint32W+0x18

// Access violation from Drawing thread.
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xe
ntdll!RtlRaiseStatus+0x26
ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+0x204
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x46
gdi32!CreateFontIndirectExW+0x26
gdi32!CreateFontIndirectW+0x61
```

What are the possible reasons of crashing GetTextExtentPoint32 and CreateFontIndirect. I never got two access violations in an application. How it happens ?. This application is almost stable and I never got an access violation from these points. I tried to call CreateFontIndirect( NULL ) to get an access violation, but its not crashing..
Please help me to find a reason..

Comment: `The synchronization between these threads are correct.` ... Are you **sure**?

Answer (score 1):

You have two different threads processing GDI calls at the same.  If these calls involve the same device contexts or GDI objects, then you have a bug in your thread synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely [closed a handle twice by accident, or otherwise corrupted the critical section](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/11/1259599.aspx).